# Cant save picture in asp.net core using CopyTo(Datastream)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, filestream

via OAuth, I have retrieved a user picture from facebook, but when I try to save it, it gives errors

I get the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'destination' of 'string.CopyTo(int, char[],
>   int, int)'    Login   C:\Users\ehioz\OneDrive\Documents\MEGAsync\IT
>   Projects\Izevbaye\Login\Controllers\AccountController.cs  364 Active

```
string pic = infos.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var pictures = $"https://graph.facebook.com/{pic}/picture?type=large";              
string path = he.WebRootPath + "/OAuth/users/" + infos+"/"+pic + "/";
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

var fileName = Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(pictures));
var DestinationStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
pictures.CopyTo(DestinationStream); 
//System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

DestinationStream.Flush();
DestinationStream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pictures` variable is simply a string. The fact that that string is a URL is meaningless. It's not going to automatically go fetch the image data for you; it's just a string. You'll need to make a request for the image via `HttpClient`:

```
using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(pictures))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatus && response.Content != null)
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
    }
}
```

As far as getting an instance of `HttpClient` to work with goes, that could be as simple as just `var _httpClient = new HttpClient();`. However, creating too many instances of `HttpClient` can exhaust your connection pool, so it's preferable to use a singleton or factory pattern. ASP.NET Core 2+ helpfully comes built-in with `IHttpClientFactory` that can be used to create and retrieve `HttpClient` instances, so you should inject and use that instead. You can also (depending on where this code lives) inject `HttpClient` directly and define an instance to be injected for a particular type in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyImageFetchingClass>();
```

This won't work out of the box with things like controllers, though, because controllers are not registered as services. While you can change that, it's preferable to use an intermediary type. You inject `HttpClient` into that type, and then inject that type in your controller. That way, the `HttpClient` logic is encapsulated and kept out of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

For [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-2.2), it supports `.Net Core 2.2 2.1 2.0`, you could try simple below:

```
string picture = @"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf6qO.jpg?s=64&g=1";
string path = _hosting.WebRootPath + "/OAuth/users/";
var fileName = Path.Combine(path, "test.jpg");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(picture), fileName);
```